# Create Mock object that doesn't have setters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm a newbie using NUnit&Moq and I'm trying to create a complex mock object to use in my unitTest project. The main problem that I have is that the object I'm mocking doesn't have defined set in their properties. As result I can't compile the following code.

```
m_objectMock.Object.Id = "myMockId";
```

Is there another way to achieve this assignation without adding setters to the class I want to test?.

Comment: You have to mock the getter to allways return your desired value.

Comment: So in a Moq we NEVER assign any value?

Comment: Sure, if you CAN. But as in your case this is not always possible and also not needed as you do not want to test the class to mock but to fake it.

Comment: Ok. So I must to use a Lambda expression defining the value I want to get I suppose? Thank you!

Comment: Lambda? Probably not. You need something like this: `mockObject.MyProperty.Returns(myValue)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With moq, use the `.Setup` method:

```
m_objectMock.Setup(m => m.Id).Returns("myMockId");
```

This means when the consuming code calls the mock for the value of `Id` the mock object will return `myMockId`.

See the properties section on the [Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart).